# Pass run time arguments to Nodejs child process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to compile C program using Nodejs child process.

C .out file execute function:

```
var exec= require('child_process').exec;
    exec("test.exe",function(err,stdout,stdin){
            //call back handling code here
    });
```

C program :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char msg[8];
 scanf("Please endter %s",&msg)
  printf("Hello world %s\n", msg);
  return 0;
}
```

How to pass runtime scanf input arguments to child process?

Comment: did you try passing it like `exec("test.exe message",function(){})`.

Comment: That works if my main method experts any arguments from CLI, but this does not work for scanf input (@ runtime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf()` reads from `stdin`. Try these:

node script:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cp = exec('test.exe', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  process.stdout.write(stdout);
  process.stderr.write(stderr);
});
cp.stdin.end('node.js');
```

C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char msg[8];
  scanf("%7s", msg);
  printf("Hello world %s\n", msg);
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs: `Hello world node.js`